# How to put a page into the left index of a site (SP 2013 on-premise)

Tags: sharepoint-server

I created some lists and documents with Workflows.

Then I created a page like dashboard, where I put those lists.

Now I want this page to appear on the left side as Site Content. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the left navigation and add a link to your page.

Have a look here for info about navigation:

[Customize the navigation on your team site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-navigation-on-your-team-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)

Comment: Well thats strange, because i was thinking to do it like that, but was unable to. Eventually i went to the right top side, site setting, there under quicklaunch i was able to ad a page link. But i wonder why i cannt use your method. ideas on that ?.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this limitation either but looks like the functionality is limited to certain site templates: https://sharepintblog.com/2013/04/26/sharepoint-edit-links-drag-and-drop-navigation-option-missing/. Maybe this explains why you are not seeing the edit links option.